# Database Location in Scheme

Tags: database, sqlite, scheme, racket

I have a program which make use of a local database (sqlite3 and i use db module). What i want to do is using the database without knowing where it is.

For example, if i code the location of database in my program (like C:/my documents/my program/localdb.db), it is working correctly.

But if i just write "localdb.db", it doesn't find the database even if database is in the same folder with the .rkt file which use the database. (i dont know how but in earlier versions of my program, it was working).

Thus, how can i ensure to use the database without coding its location?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `"localdb.db"`, try using a runtime-path like this:

```
(define-runtime-path localdb "localdb.db")
```

and use `localdb` in place of the path string. You'll need to `(require racket/runtime-path)`.

Comment: Is there a way like this to get know the concrete directory of database? @Asumu Takikawa

Comment: You can call `split-path` on the runtime path to get that.